# "yes" command with finite number of "yes" answers

Tags: wget, pipe

The `yes` command in linux is used to provide automatic "yes" answers to command prompts in linux:

`yes | wget https://example.com`

The issue is that, after execution of `wget` command the `yes` command keeps working and does not let the whole above command to finish. How can I make the `yes` command to provide finite numbers of "yes" answers?

Comment: `repeat 10 echo yes`?

Comment: For your example, no "yes" is needed, so it is difficult to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Explain please. I have never seen a wget where it required  a "yes".  If you need to overwrite a file use `-O`

Comment: A more advanced tool, that can do what you want is `expect`, (available via the program package with the same name). It can provide a set of various answers depending on what 'questions you expect'. Tutorials can be found via the internet.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Use <del>your</del> `head`.

While I understand the confusion in the comments regarding your use case:

> `$ wget --help`
>
> GNU Wget 1.14, a **non-interactive** network retriever.
> [...]

I'd still like to answer this question, for educational purposes. And because I needed a finite number of input lines for another reason and this thread was the first search result on my browser.

I assume the following examples speak for themselves:

```
$ yes | head -5
y
y
y
y
y
```

```
$ yes absolutely | head -2
absolutely
absolutely
```

So, theoretically, in your example it would be

```
$ yes | head -1 | wget https://example.com
```

Which still does not make sense, because `wget` is not asking you anything.